# Add Int[] array into List<int[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm having trouble with int[] arrays and adding them to a List<>. I'd like to add the values of my int[] array to something each loop but every time I do this my "something" gets the same value for every element I add. Very annoying. I understand arrays are always reference vars. However even the "new" key word doesn't seem to help. What needs to happen is to add result to some enumerated object like a List or Array or ArrayList.

Here's the codility question:

You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

- increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
- max_counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.

A non-empty zero-indexed array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

- if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
- if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max_counter.

For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
```

the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:

```
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 3, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 4, 2)
```

The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

I copied some code from others and the variable "result" does indeed load the data correctly. I just wanted to copy it back to the main program so I could see it. The only method that works is += add it into a string. Thus losing any efficiency I might have gained.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testarray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = new int[7];
            A[0] = 3;
            A[1] = 4;
            A[2] = 4;
            A[3] = 6;
            A[4] = 1;
            A[5] = 4;
            A[6] = 4;
            List<int[]> finish = solution(5, A);

        }
        public static List<int[]> solution(int N, int[] A)
        {
            int[] result = new int[N];
            int maximum = 0;
            int resetlimit = 0;
            int iter = 0;
            List<int[]> collected_result = new List<int[]>;

            for (int K = 0; K < A.Length; K++)
            {
                if (A[K] < 1 || A[K] > N + 1)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }

                if (A[K] >= 1 && A[K] <= N)
                {
                    if (result[A[K] - 1] < resetlimit)
                    {
                        result[A[K] - 1] = resetlimit + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result[A[K] - 1]++;
                    }

                    if (result[A[K] - 1] > maximum)
                    {
                        maximum = result[A[K] - 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    resetlimit = maximum;
                    result = Enumerable.Repeat(maximum, result.Length).ToArray<int>();

                }

                collected_result.Add(result);

            }
                  //    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                  //result[i] = Math.max(resetLimit, result[i]);

            return collected_result;
        }

    }
}
```

This doesn't work, the collected_result ends up like:

```
(0,0,1,2,0)
(0,0,1,2,0)
(0,0,1,2,0)
(3,2,2,4,2)
(3,2,2,4,2)
(3,2,2,4,2)
(3,2,2,4,2)
```

I know it's the line collected_result.Add(result); adding the reference each time to every instance of result in the List<>. Bother. I've tried adding "new" which is a compiler error. Finally in desperation I just added everything to a very long string. Can someone help me figure out how to properly load an object to pass back to main?

Comment: Do not use weird and complex solution. There are more than one way to reach your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to go:

Get a copy of your array before adding it to list:

```
collected_result.Add(result.ToArray());
```

Comment: Excellent, that was elegant. I could not see how to stop referencing the reference. The method ToArray() must act as kind of a "new". I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python solution:
def solution(A, N):
    lenA = len(A)
    k = 0
    max_counter_value = 0
    counters = [0 for x in range(0, N)]

```
for k in range(0, lenA):
    if A[k] >= 1 and A[k] <= N:
        counters[A[k] - 1] += 1
        max_counter_value = max(counters)
    if A[k] == N + 1:
        counters = [max_counter_value for x in range(0, N)]
    print counters
```

A = [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4]
N = 5

solution(A, N)